# Magento 2. How can I have some categories show products in Grid View, while others show it in List view?

Tags: magento2

I have a website where I need to show some products in Grid view while others are in List view. How is this possible in Magento 2? Does anyone know about an extension for this? Or can it be set up in the code?

Comment: yes it be set up in code. Suppose 10 products in category first 5 products will be show in grid view and rest will show in list view.

Comment: You need to  add filter in collection.

Answer (score 0):

Need to filter the product collection. Look into this reference link.

[Magento Collection](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/22/magento-part12-series-collection-sql-operations/)